# Error: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

So I am trying to make a CNN model for crowdcounting, this is the structure.

```
    self.base = nn.Sequential(Conv2d( 1, 64 ,3, same_padding=True, bn=bn),
                              Conv2d(64, 64 ,3, same_padding=True, bn=bn),
                              nn.MaxPool2d(2),
                              Conv2d( 64, 128 ,3, same_padding=True, bn=bn),
                              Conv2d(128, 128 ,3, same_padding=True, bn=bn))
    
    self.layer1_1 = nn.Sequential(nn.MaxPool2d(2),
                                  Conv2d(128, 256 ,3, same_padding=True, bn=bn))
    self.layer1_2 = nn.Sequential(Conv2d(256, 256 ,3, same_padding=True, bn=bn))
    self.layer1_3 = nn.Sequential(Conv2d(256, 256 ,3, same_padding=True, bn=bn))
    
    self.fuse_layer1 = nn.Sequential(nn.MaxPool2d(2),
                                     Conv2d(256, 256 ,3, same_padding=True, bn=bn))
    
    
    self.layer2_1 = nn.Sequential(nn.MaxPool2d(2),
                                  Conv2d(256, 512 ,3, same_padding=True, bn=bn))
    self.layer2_2 = nn.Sequential(Conv2d(512, 512 ,3, same_padding=True, bn=bn))
    self.layer2_3 = nn.Sequential(Conv2d(512, 512 ,3, same_padding=True, bn=bn))
                                
    self.fuse_layer2 = nn.Sequential(Conv2d(512, 256 ,3, same_padding=True, bn=bn))
    
    
    self.layer3_1 = nn.Sequential(nn.MaxPool2d(2),
                                  Conv2d(512, 512 ,3, same_padding=True, bn=bn))
    self.layer3_2 = nn.Sequential(Conv2d(512, 512 ,3, same_padding=True, bn=bn))
    self.layer3_3 = nn.Sequential(Conv2d(512, 512 ,3, same_padding=True, bn=bn))
    
    self.fuse_layer3 = nn.Sequential(Conv2d(512, 256 ,3, same_padding=True, bn=bn))
    
    
    self.fuse_layers = nn.Sequential(Conv2d(768, 1 ,1, same_padding=True, bn=bn))
```

When joining the layers in the forward method:

```
def forward(self, im_data):
   
    base_layer = self.base(im_data)    
    l1_1 = self.layer1_1(base_layer)
    l1_2 = self.layer1_2(l1_1)
    l1_3 = self.layer1_3(l1_2)
    fuse_l1 = self.fuse_layer1(l1_1.add(l1_2).add(l1_3))
    print(fuse_l1.size())
    
    l2_1 = self.layer2_1(l1_3)
    l2_2 = self.layer2_2(l2_1)
    l2_3 = self.layer2_3(l2_2)
    fuse_l2 = self.fuse_layer2(l2_1.add(l2_2).add(l2_3))
    print(fuse_l2.size())
    
    l3_1 = self.layer3_1(l2_3)
    l3_2 = self.layer3_2(l3_1)
    l3_3 = self.layer3_3(l3_2)
    fuse_l3 = self.fuse_layer3(l3_1.add(l3_2).add(l3_3))
    upsample = nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 256, 3, stride=2, padding=1)
    fuse_l3 = upsample(fuse_l3, output_size = fuse_l2.size())
    print(fuse_l3.size())
    
    fuse_all = self.fuse_layers(torch.cat((fuse_l1,fuse_l2,fuse_l3),1))
    
    
    return fuse_all
```

[The important this of all of this is fuse_l1, fuse_l2 and fuse_l3, these 3 are torch tensors and here are their sizes:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jncSt.png)

I've been searching to upscale this tensor and found that ConvTranspose2d will do the job.

```
upsample = nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 256, 3, stride=2, padding=1)
fuse_l3 = upsample(fuse_l3, output_size = fuse_l2.size())
```

I've tested this with dummy tensors and works fine, but with these real tensors spot the error:
"Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same"

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This error usually comes up when you send your tensors to the gpu but not the model. Try

```
device = torch.device('cuda')`
model.to(device)
```